# I want to develop code in vue.Js using vuetify which take input through textfield and display two string values on display after the button click

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am knida new to vue.js please help me to solve problem.

I want to develop code in vue.Js using vuetify which take input through textfield and display two string values on display after the button click.

Here is the code

[image: 1]

Comment: Hey, what did you try, can you share the code?

Comment: it is resolved thanks.

Comment: I want place textfield in the middle but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's why I asked you to share your code. without code it's not possible to understand your issue.

Comment: it is updated now

Comment: And what is inside your name() function.